# Error 1609 when installing MSI in docker

Tags: docker, windows-installer

Anyone have a clue?
The MSI (self developed) works fine on local machines.  I suspect that the issue may be that 
1)It needs to be elevated
2)It is installing to GAC32

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
ADD API ./API
Run msiexec.exe /i "/API/proCubeAPIADO.msi" /qn
```

Comment: Try adding some logging flags to get something out of this else very hard to tell. windowsservercore has limited components compared to windows. So it works in local really doesn't matter

Comment: Error 1609 is kind of a catch all error and not very useful. Try adding /L*V <logfilePath> to the end of the msiexec command line so that it will generate a log. The log will probably give much more information to troubleshoot.

Comment: OK, so I finally got around to trying some different stuff, and now I'm getting something I totally didn't expect - I get NOTHING if I try above again.

Now I'm also trying:
    FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:3.5
    ADD API ./API

and running it with docker built, then in another powershell window window and attaching via 
    docker exec -it mycontaner powershell

An trying to run 
    msiexec.exe /i procubeapiado.msi /qn /L /V mylog.txt 

and nothing appears to happen